# Toggle in tables using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show the table rows when i click the th, but i have no idea how to do it.
here's what i have for now:

```
    <th colspan="3" class="subth">Empresa São João</th>
                        <tr class="hidethis">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Linha Tangerina</td>
                            <td>R$ 20,05</td>
                        </tr>
```

and the JQuery/JavaScript is like this:

```
                        $('.hidethis').hide();   
                        $('.subth').click(function(){
                            $(this).next().toggle();
                        });
```

I mean, if this part of the code isn't enough i can send more after

*edit: *
The hide is working, what isn't working is the toggle!
thanks

If i use this:
    `$('tbody').click(function(){
         $(this).find('tr').toggle();
    });`

it "works"
the thing is: I have two th's with tr's, so both of them show at the same time.

*edit 2.0: *

Guys, i kind of got it!
I mean, it's not perfect because it'll be always showing one set of `<tr>` but it's fine i guess
Here's the code that i came up with
(It's probably fucked up, lol)

```
$('.hidethis2').hide();   

$('tbody').click(function(){
     $('tr.hidethis').toggle();
     $('tr.hidethis2').toggle();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think `tr` elements are wrapped in `tbody`. Inspect the element to have better idea...

Comment: oh
what do i do then? just delete tbody?

Comment: A `<th>`, or `<td>`, element should be wrapped in a `<tr>` element; if they aren't the browser will try to 'rescue' the invalid HTML when constructing the DOM.

Comment: Just use more specific selector... `$(this).closest('thead').next(....)`

Comment: I got the tbody thingy, sorry for being so dumb.
I'll try other selectors.

Also, i didn't post it but there are two th's. And yea, they are wrapped in a <tr>

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```js
$('th').click(function(ev) {
  $(this).parent('tr').next('.row').toggleClass('hide');
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In my opinion this is cleaner than 3 chained jQuery Selectors.

Comment: Dear @l0rin – Won't it apply `toggleClass` over all the `.row` elements ?

Comment: I did not know he will have multiple, i'll adjust the example!

Comment: Yea! I have two.
I'm trying this: 
                         `$('tbody').click(function(){
                                    $('tr.hidethis').toggle();
                           });`
and it "works" but it shows both of them at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('th').click(function(){
$('.next-tr').fadeToggle();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr height="25">
  <th width="50%">1St</th>
    <th width="50%">2Nd</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="next-tr">
  <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It is your solution..

```
<table border="1px">
<tr>
    <th colspan="3" class="subth">
        My header
    </th>
</tr>
 <tr class="hidethis">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Linha Tangerina</td>
    <td>R$ 20,05</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And jQuery File is:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".subth").click(function(){
        $(".hidethis").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Think that, it is your solution ..thanks..